# D3 circle packing - swithc color for each branch

Tags: d3.js, circle-pack

I have a d3 circle packing, and I would like to find an elegant way to color each branch differently. I have a depth property, so it is easy to apply a gradient based on it.
To color each branch differently I think it requires to know what color has been attributed to the precedent sibling but I am not sure how to find it.
Any help is appreciated, I am not sure how to get started.

thanks

the coloring is produced by the following that will return a color based on the depth in the tree:

```
var color = d3.scale
      .linear()
      .domain([-1, 5])
      .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
      .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

    function color_for_node(node) {
      var out;
      //some other operation removed here for simplification
      out = node.children ? color(node.depth) : null;
      return out;
    }
```

It is then used by the following (simplified) :

```
  circle = svg
          .selectAll("circle")
          .data(nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .someOtherStuff()
          .style("fill", color_for_node)  //<--used here
```

(I am working on a solution, I will edit this again once it is done. The key in this solution is not really depending on D3, but on the data tree. Luckily I found out that each node references its parent, so I think it is possible to find out of a node belongs to a specific branch which what I am doing now  )

Comment: Some code would help greatly. But you could try classing the branches then using css to color them.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was confused by the task when I started, hence the confused question. Hopefully I will be able to answer it myself soon.

Comment: Dear downvoters, now there is some research done, and an answer posted by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution. Since d3 collection are properly ordered, every time a root branch node is met, it is followed by its childs, until it reaches another root branch node. Therefore we can effectively switch the color from one branch to another without havin gto check the parents of each node, which would be costly computation.

```
        const ranges = [
      ["hsl(120,0%,90%)", "hsl(120,0%,50%)"], //grey
      ["hsl(228,80%,80%)", "hsl(300,30%,40%)"], //light blue
      ["hsl(300,80%,80%)", "hsl(360,30%,40%)"], //light pink to brick
      ["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"], //light green-blue
      ["hsl(80,80%,80%)", "hsl(120,30%,40%)"], //light yellow-green
      ["hsl(120,80%,80%)", "hsl(150,30%,40%)"], //light green
      ["hsl(0,80%,80%)", "hsl(40,30%,40%)"], //light pink to brown
      ["hsl(40,80%,80%)", "hsl(80,30%,40%)"] //sand
    ];
    let rangeIndex = 0;
    const color = node => {
      let range = ranges[rangeIndex];
      if (node.depth === 1) {
        rangeIndex = rangeIndex < ranges.length - 1 ? rangeIndex + 1 : 0;
        range = ranges[rangeIndex];
      }

      return d3.scale
        .linear()
        .domain([-1, 5])
        .range(range)
        .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl)(node.depth);
    };
```